# Proper release of UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios4, uiimageview, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm a bit confused with this as I've seen way too many different variants and not sure which one is the correct way. Currently I have:

```
- (IBAction)pickImageFromLibrary:(id)sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

    //  [picker release];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{   
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 10.0f, 320.0f, 264.0f)];

    self.studyView = imageView;

    [imageView release];

    [self.tableView setTableHeaderView:studyView];

    self.fitImage = [ImageHelper image:image fitInView:studyView];

    if (picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera)
    {
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
    }

    studyView.image = self.fitImage;

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    [picker release];
 }
```

I'm allocating the `UIImagePickerController` in the first method but wouldn't it be logical to only release it in the 2nd method when I dismiss it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, because it's retained when presented modally, via `presentModelViewController`. This is the common pattern you'll find when presenting new view controllers, whether modally, custom view controllers or not. This is fine:

```
- (IBAction)pickImageFromLibrary:(id)sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

    [picker release];
}
```

Comment: Cool thanks. That means I don't need the release in the didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo one :)